# How to store Key and Values as JSON in Redis using Spring Data Redis?

Tags: spring, redis, spring-data-redis

I am developing `Spring Data Redis` example with `Spring Boot`. In this example, I am looking to store all keys and values as json format. Using `CrudRepository` pattern to perform `CRUD` operations. Do I need to set any configurations to that keys can be stored as JSON ? I went through the link : https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/, but not clear where to set confogurations.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> SMEMBERS user:2be0135f-dbda-490c-8cf9-cd9a7bfdce1b:idx
1) "user:firstName:John"
2) "user:lastName:Kerr"
3) "user:role.roleName:API"
4) "user:middleName:Lima"
127.0.0.1:6379> HGETALL user:2be0135f-dbda-490c-8cf9-cd9a7bfdce1b
 1) "_class"
 2) "com.baeldung.spring.data.redis.model.User"
 3) "id"
 4) "2be0135f-dbda-490c-8cf9-cd9a7bfdce1b"
 5) "firstName"
 6) "John"
 7) "middleName"
 8) "Lima"
 9) "lastName"
10) "Kerr"
11) "role.id"
12) "R2"
13) "role.roleName"
14) "API"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

Role.java

```
@RedisHash("Role")
public class Role {
    private @Id String id;
    private @Indexed String roleName;
}
```

User.java

```
@RedisHash("user")
public class User {
    private @Id String id;
    private @Indexed String firstName;
    private @Indexed String middleName;
    private @Indexed String lastName;
    private Role role;
}
```

RedisConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties
@EnableRedisRepositories("com.baeldung.spring.data.redis.repository")
public class RedisConfig {
    @Bean
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        return new JedisConnectionFactory();
    }
    @Bean
    RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate() {
        final RedisTemplate<Object, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
        template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setHashValueSerializer(new GenericToStringSerializer<Object>(Object.class));
        template.setValueSerializer(new GenericToStringSerializer<Object>(Object.class));
        return template;
    }
}
```

MainApp.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Transactional
public class MainAppDemo implements CommandLineRunner{
    RedisMappingContext mappingContext = new RedisMappingContext();
    ExampleQueryMapper mapper = new ExampleQueryMapper(mappingContext, new PathIndexResolver(mappingContext));

    @Autowired private UserRepository userRepository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainAppDemo.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        Role role1 = Role.builder().id("R1").roleName("ADMIN").build();
        User user1 = User.builder().firstName("Matt").middleName("Mike").lastName("Wixson").role(role1).build();

        Role role2 = Role.builder().id("R2").roleName("API").build();
        User user2 = User.builder().firstName("John").middleName("Lima").lastName("Kerr").role(role2).build();

        userRepository.save(user1);
        userRepository.save(user2); 

    }
}
```

Comment: Which of the options from chapters 5.7, 5.8 and 8.3 did you try and what problems did you have?

Comment: I've not used RedisTemplate for any of the CRUD operation. Its via the CRUD Repository. Please suggest now.

Comment: @Tomasz Poradowski - Could you please guide ?

Comment: Hi, is this issue resolved?